# Parse json in php after ajax post request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Suppose there is the javascript with `ajax` request   -

**index.js-**

```
var dataFeedback = $("#feedback_popup_message_body").val();
var jsonObj = JSON.stringify({dataFeedback: dataFeedback});
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: jsonObj,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

and in the server side  , php page  -

**index.php-**

```
<?php
    $myPostData = json_decode($_POST["dataFeedback"]);
    $feedback = $myPostData["dataFeedback"];
    echo $feedback;
?>
```

I try to send with the request a `json` object and once it parsed in the server side, get it back to the client page and logs its data .

In the above concept it doesn't logs the data value .

I checked it in `Chrome > F12 > Networks > index.php > Response` and found this  -

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: dataFeedback in <b>...\index.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
```

How to cause it to logs the `data` which backs from the server ?

**Update: The code that finally cause it works -**

**index.js-**

```
var dataFeedback = $("#feedback_popup_message_body").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "bin/bll/suggestionSummary.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {dataFeedback: dataFeedback},
    success: function (data) {

        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**index.php-**

```
<?php
    $myPostData = $_POST['dataFeedback'];
    echo $myPostData;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have simply value than why are you using JSON.stringify?
Try this...

```
var dataFeedback =  $("#feedback_popup_message_body").val();
var jsonObj  = JSON.stringify({dataFeedback:dataFeedback});
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { dataFeedback:dataFeedback },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Now you can get value direct with $_POST['dataFeedback'];

Comment: Tried it  , now it doesn't appear any response in - `Chrome > F12 > Networks > index.php > Response` but still doesn't logs the `data` which back from the server  .

Comment: Are you sure your php file not sending empty response. Please check it. May be you find something. Use alert your response.

Comment: Ok ... it work with just `$myPostData = $_POST['dataFeedback'];` in the php with no more parsing . 
I'll update the works code in my post .

Answer (score 1):

You're sending raw JSON as the request data, so you can't access it using `$_POST` on the PHP side, because that only works with form encoded key/value pairs.

You will need to access the raw post data like so, on the PHP side:

```
$data = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
echo $data->dataFeedback;
```

Finally, you are not outputting JSON on the PHP side, so remove `dataType: 'json',`, otherwise jQuery will try to parse the response as JSON and invoke the error handler.

Answer (score 1):

jsonObj is a plain string not an array anymore.

What you probably want:

```
var dataFeedback =  $("#feedback_popup_message_body").val();
    var jsonObj  = JSON.stringify(dataFeedback);
    $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data : {dataFeedback: jsonObj },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Now $_POST['dataFeedback'] will be set.

If you want to use associative arrays after json_decode you need to do (notice the second parameter true):

```
$myPostData = json_decode($_POST["dataFeedback"], true);
```